# Ver estrutura de uma view WORKBENCH

Tags: mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá , 
criei uma view no workbench,

porém preciso saber como faço para ver a estrutura dela.

tipo, saber os selects que ela está fazendo

há alguma forma ?

Comment: tem como clicar no botão direito e editar?

Answer (score 0):

CONSEGUI GALERA.

SEGUE A FOTO
BASTA CLICAR NA FERRAMENTA AO LADO DO NOME

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]